# Sql statement not adding actual dat to database

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I am trying to make a sign in window for an application with tkinter and sqlite3 but all it sends to the data base repeatedly is that the username is ".!toplevel.!entry" and password is ".!toplevel.!entry2". Please help thanks

```
def createlogin():
global username
global password
top= Toplevel()
top.title("SmartCards - New User")
top.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Comp NEA\Icon.ico")
top.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

def submit1():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", ("username, password,"),)
    conn.commit()   
    
username = Entry(top)
username.insert(0,"Username: ")
username.grid(row=0, column=0)
username=str(username)
password = Entry(top)
password.insert(0,"Password: ")
password.grid(row=1, column=0)
password=str(password)
submit = Button(top, text="Submit", command=submit1)
submit.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: `str()` is not the right way to fetch the contents of an Entry.  Why are you trying to do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

- `username = str(username)` will set `username` to the name of the entry widget `username`. Same for `password`.
- passing `"username, password,"` as the second argument of `c.execute()` which raises exception because a tuple/list of two items is expected
- `global ...` is not necessary

Note also that you should get the contents of the entry boxes inside `submit1()` instead.

Below is the modified code:

```py
def createlogin():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("SmartCards - New User")
    top.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Comp NEA\Icon.ico")
    top.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

    def submit1():
        # get the inputs here
        user = username.get()
        passwd = password.get()
        # pass (user, passwd) as second argument
        c.execute("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (user, passwd))
        conn.commit()

    username = Entry(top)
    username.insert(0,"Username: ")
    username.grid(row=0, column=0)
    password = Entry(top)
    password.insert(0,"Password: ")
    password.grid(row=1, column=0)
    submit = Button(top, text="Submit", command=submit1)
    submit.grid(row=2, column=0)
```